# Shake no longer works after a UIAlertview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uialertview

I have tested this on both an iPad and the iPad Simulator and after one successful shake, the motionBegan method is never called. The following is a snippet of my program.

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  if(event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake)
  {
    NSLog(@"Shake event occurred.");

            UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" message:@"Some message here" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            alert.tag = shakeTag;
            [alert show];

  }
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
return YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:NO];
  [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:NO];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [self resignFirstResponder];
  [super viewDidDisappear:NO];
}
```

What exactly is preventing the motionBegan method from occurring again? I would like the UIAlertView to be presented exactly once for the first shake and dismissed for all subsequent shakes. I have a hunch that the First Responder is still attached to the UIAlertView which is preventing the motionBegan method from being called again.

**Update**: In my corresponding UIView, there is an UIActionSheet that is created.  which is called and implemented in my UIView) and I trigger the motionBegan method (which is in my UIViewController) at the same time which the UIActionSheet is displayed on the screen, the problem where the motionBegan method no longer being able to be called exists.

Afterwards, the UIAlertView is dismissed from any button selection, the motionBegan method no longer is called but the UIActionSheet works perfectly fine. There is no firstResponder assignment in UIView and only the "canBecomeFirstResponder" exists in the UIViewController. Any ideas?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it worked repeatedly on an iPad simulator (the only thing I took out was the alert.tag = shakeTag line).

Comment: @rdelmar It does not work for me on an iPAD simulator. The Hardware Shake gesture no longer calls motionBegan since there is only one output of the following line: "NSLog(@"Shake event occurred.");"
I have the following method to handle that specific alert tag, "- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex"

Comment: Well, I have no idea why yours doesn't work. I added the tag and the alert delegate method, and it still works fine for me.

Comment: @rdelmar Is this in your viewcontroller class?

Comment: Yes it is. Isn't yours?

Comment: @rdelmar Mine is,yes. I am sorry but I forgot to point out the I have a UIActionSheet created and on the screen from my view. Is this what is causing the problem?

Comment: Probably so. I'm guessing that the action sheet is the first responder, so the controller is not getting the shake events.

Comment: @rdelmar That's what I believe is the problem. What would be the best way to resolve this issue? I would like the UIAlertview to have first priority and after it dismisses I would like to return control back to the UIActionSheet and then repeat this entire process.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25996/discussion-between-david-and-rdelmar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since that code is in your viewController, remove all the stuff related to responder chain. You don't need it actually. It is made automatically for you. More precisely you can remove:

   ```
   - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder // remove all that method
   {
   return YES;
   }

     [self becomeFirstResponder]; // remove this line

   ...
     [self resignFirstResponder]; // remove this line
   ...
   ```

   and remove this as well all that method

   ```
   -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   }
   ```
2. Call your alertView stuff in motionEnd instead motionBegan. It could be better.

Comment: What are the stuff related to the responder chain exactly?